# Type Error - generating final archive: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 13 , Type: Android packaging problem

Tags: android, installation

I have a weird problem. I have installed windows 7 on my machine.
For android installation i have downloaded the latest android sdk, installed plugins, set the paths and all... as i have done it several times....

But when i create a new sample project and compile it it shows red cross on the project in Package explorer and i am not able to run the program.(I have compiled the project successfully and it is not the R.java file error... :-) )

In the Problem window it shows on error and that is 
Type Error - generating final archive: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 13 , Type: Android packaging problem.

Struggling with this for last one week and getting more and more frustrated.

I will very thankful if some solve my prol

Comment: i am getting the same error.have u find the solution

Answer (score 0):

Do a `Project->Clean` in Eclipse, see if that'll help out.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this bug in my system to
  and got puzzeled and ask question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18045984/eclipse-pacakge-error-found-no-solutions

But At last i got the soulution
that worked for me

First change laguage from hindi(or some thing) to English 
delete the debug key (Can be found on my doucument and folder named ".android")
and do
"eclipse.exe -clean" from command promp

this will generate a dubug keystore and project runs normally.